# multiple keys using local storage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I'm trying the following code to generate multiple keys (user_0,user_1,user_3...) for the record(username,password,email) I'm obtaining the alert "The data was saved" but nothing is saved in the local storage.can someone help me where it's going wrong??

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
if ('localStorage' in window && window['localStorage'] !== null) {
        try {
            e=$("#email").val();
            u=$("#username").val();
            p=$("#password").val();

            function users(email,username,password){

                  this.email=email;
                  this.username=username; 
                  this.password= password; 

            }
           function createNewUser(eml,user,pass) {
                var createdUser = new users(e,u,p);
               //console.log(createdUser);
              if ( localStorage.userCount == undefined ) {
              localStorage.setItem('userCount', 0) 
                  }
             var userSize = parseInt(localStorage.userCount) + 1;
            commitToStorage(userSize,createdUser);
                }

        function commitToStorage(objectCount,newObject) {
             // The unique key of the object:
             var item = 'user' + objectCount;
            localStorage.setItem('userCount', objectCount);

             // Put the object into storage
            localStorage.setItem(item, JSON.stringify(users));
                }
             alert("The data was saved."); 
             return true;
            }catch (e) {
            if (e == QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR) {
                alert('Quota exceeded!');
            }
        }
        } else {
            alert('Cannot store user preferences as your browser do not support local storage');
        }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to store all user objects in an array, and you can use the array index to add an identifier to them if you like

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
    if ('localStorage' in window && window['localStorage'] !== null) {

        var users;
        if(!localStorage.users) { users = []; }
        else {
            users = JSON.parse(localStorage.users);
        }

        // don't stringify the data yet
        var currentUser = {
            "userNumber" : users.length,
            "email" : $("#email").val(), 
            "username" : $("#username").val(), 
            "password" : $("#password").val(), 
        };

        users.push(currentUser);

        try {            
            localStorage.users = JSON.stringify(users); 
            console.log("The data was saved."); 
            return true;          
        }
        catch (e) {
            if (e == QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR) {
            alert('Quota exceeded!');
        }
    }

    else {
        alert('Cannot store user preferences as your browser do not support local storage');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating new keys I suggest you use an array structure to store all user data:

```
$("#submit").click(function () {
    if ('localStorage' in window && window['localStorage'] !== null) {
        try {
            //Get stored data
            var users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users'));

            if (users === null) {
                //If no stored data, create empty array
                users = [];
            }

            //Create new user entry
            user = {
                email: $("#email").val(),
                username: $("#username").val(),
                password: $("#password").val(),
            };

            //Add new entry to stored array
            users.push(user);

            //Save array
            localStorage.setItem("users", JSON.stringify(users));

            alert("The data was saved.");
            return true;

        } catch (e) {
            if (e == QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR) {
                alert('Quota exceeded!');
            }
        }
    } else {
        alert('Cannot store user preferences as your browser do not support local storage');
    }
});
```

Comment: this will create one key and multiple records. what i want is to create multiple keys.my question is clear "multiple keys"

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved :D

```
$("#submit").click(function(){


    if ('localStorage' in window && window['localStorage'] !== null) {
        try {
            e=$("#email").val();
            u=$("#username").val();
            p=$("#password").val();

            createNewUser = function (eml,user,passw) {
                  var createdUser = new users(eml,user,passw);

                  if ( localStorage.userCount == undefined ) {
                      localStorage.setItem('userCount', 0) 
                  }
                  var userSize = parseInt(localStorage.userCount) + 1;
                  commitToStorage(userSize,createdUser);
                }
        function commitToStorage(objectCount,newObject) {
                  // The unique key of the object:
                  var item = 'user' + objectCount;
                  localStorage.setItem('userCount', objectCount);

                  // Put the object into storage
                  localStorage.setItem(item, JSON.stringify(newObject));
                }
        function users(email,username,password){

            this.email=email;
            this.username=username; 
            this.password= password; 

                  }
        createNewUser(e,u,p);
                 alert("The data was saved."); 
                 return true;
            }catch (e) {
            if (e == QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR) {
                alert('Quota exceeded!');
            }
        }
        } else {
            alert('Cannot store user preferences as your browser do not support local storage');
        }
        });
```